# Implementing Coin Changing Prob using Niave method

Tags: python, recursion, greedy, coin-change

I'm trying to implement Coin Changing Problem which states that

> Coin Changing problem is described as given a value N, if we want to
>   make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of S =
>   {S1, S2, . . . , Sm} valued coins, how many ways can we make the
>   change? The order of coins doesn’t matter. Identify all possible ways
>   of changing N cent by Greedy Method. For example, for N = 4 and S =
>   {1, 2, 3}, there are four solutions: {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 2},
>   {1, 3}. So output should be 4. For N = 10 and S = {2, 5, 3, 6}, there
>   are five solutions: {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 6}, {2, 3,
>   5}and{5, 5}. So the output should be 5.

Note: This not the original Coin changing problem where we have to find the optimal solution (i.e. Minimum No. of coins)

In my below python implementation, I'm using a list name called $check$. Problem is that the program is using same $check$ list throughout its run time and hence I'm getting wrong result. It should use the $check$ list which is local to its function call. Can anybody find a way out of this..

```
# N
N = 10

# Set of Changes
s = [2, 3, 5, 6]

lst = []
check = [0, 0, 0, 0]

def Coin_Change_Count(C, check):       
    for k in range(len(s)):        
        i = len(s) - k - 1
        t = C - s[i]

        if (t >= 0):
            if (s[i] == 2):
                check[0] += 1
            elif (s[i] == 3):
                check[1] += 1
            elif (s[i] == 5):
                check[2] += 1
            elif (s[i] == 6):
                check[3] += 1

            if (t >= s[0]):
                Coin_Change_Count(t, check)

            if (t == 0):
                if (not (check in lst)):
                    lst.append(check)

Coin_Change_Count(N, check)
print(len(lst))
```

Comment: You have a global variable `check` and a function parameter `check`. Rename either one for clarity. Also read the Python docs to find out how to use globals at all, the lookup rules might be a bit surprising. BTW: Since you only pass the global `check` to the function, the global and local variables are always identical. You might want to copy the list. That said, can you give a reference to this Niave Method that you are trying to implement?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Actually its a assignment given in my Algorithm Lab and the procedure I'm using is mine only.